# Add xmp extension schema with itext to be PDF/A compliant

Tags: itext, xmp, pdfa

I am looking for a working **iText** version 5.5.4 example to add a custom metadata value `myProp` with content like `<custom>My metadata</custom>` to a PDF document. We can't use existing schemas like DC for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *5.x.x* - which 5.x.x version? There have been many fixes in this regard in the course of the 5.x.x versions.

Comment: Correct: somewhere along the way, we switched from using our own XML library to using Adobe's standard Java implementation of XMP, so the version really matters.

Comment: I'am looking for a simple code example for version 5.5.4.